# python - Imprimir os elementos da lista que terminam com a letra ‘a’

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Considerando a seguinte lista:

*`lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre',]`**

O que pretendo é imprimir os elementos da lista que terminam com a letra ‘a’.

Bem, para uma lista de inteiros, poderia fazer assim:

```
>>> L = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
>>> L[-1]
21
```

Sei que poderia fazer assim:

```
    lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre',]


print(lista_nomes[1:2])
print(lista_nomes[5:6])
print(lista_nomes[4:5])
```

Mas não acho que esteja bem!

Alguma ideia, por favor?!

Obrigado,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica para 'agarrar' o ultimo elemento de cada nome (ultima letra) é a mesma (`nome[-1]`). Visto que uma string em muitas linguagens é também um iterável, e python não foge à regra:

Para imprimires todos os nomes cujo ultimo caracter é "a":

```
lista_nomes = ['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre',]
for nome in lista_nomes:
  if(nome[-1] == 'a'): # verificar se ultimo caracter e um 'a'
    print(nome)
# Laura, Maria, Silvia
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/CanineDarkorchidKeychanger)

Caso queiras uma lista só com os nomes que terminam 'a' (usando [compreensão de lista](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)):

```
lista_nomes = ['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre']
nomes_a = [nome for nome in lista_nomes if nome[-1] == 'a'] # ['Laura', 'Maria', 'Silvia']
```

Comment: É isso mesmo que queria!!! Muito obrigado!!! Excelente!

Comment: @JoaoPeixotoFernandes, podes fazer o mesmo do meu ultimo exemplo num `for`: https://repl.it/repls/PrimeMilkyBot

Comment: Sim, eu sei. Era mesmo isso!! :)

Comment: Como disseste "O que pretendo é imprimir...", daí ter feito o primeiro exemplo com `print`. Para a próxima diz que pretendes uma lista (;

Comment: o que pretendia era mesmo com o for ! Obrigado.